# SSIS connection manager error with PostgreSQL 'Value does not fall within the expected range'

Tags: postgresql, ssis

I have very simple SSIS package which brings 8 columns from PostgreSQL into SQL server. There are only 10 rows feeding through. Now requirement changed by adding another 
- join 
- with extra column to bring back. 
- Also one where clause condition to be removed.

When changed and preview using OLE DB source editor it throws error 'Value does not fall within the expected range'

script runs successfully in PostgreSQL within 40 sec(though it should not take that long).

In 'OLE DB source editor:
When adding Join - it previews(successfully)
when adding Join and bringing column - it previews (successfully)
when adding Join, bringing column and removing condition ( condition let it bring 149 records instead of 10 ) - (throws error)

I guess it is very basic error and someone with experience will be able to spot it quickly. Will be very thankful for kind and prompt response..

- I have checked datatype for new column source and destination and it matches. character (255)
- I have run script using PGAdmin 4 and it runs successfully in PostgreSQL.

.

Comment: Can you add more info about your script?

Comment: Inspect the values. Most likely one of them breaks the 255 chars limit